# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints - while adding subview

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm using a storyboard among with the xib.

I have the `UIViewController` loaded from storyboard and `UIView` loaded from xib. I'm trying to add xib as a subview to storyboard `UIViewController` and set it's bottom constratint like this:

```
TransactionsPickerViewController *_picker = [[TransactionsPickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:picker.view];

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:picker.view
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:self.view
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                            multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

It causes this in debug console:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want...

UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1090509e0 UIView:0x109440be0.bottom == UIView:0x109619ba0.bottom>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x109052400 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x109440be0.midY == UIView:0x109619ba0.midY - 140>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x109052470 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x109440be0.height == UIView:0x109619ba0.height - 280>"
)
```

Where are those autoresizing properties coming from and can I get rid off them to make it work? Baically I want my picker view stick to the parent view bottom after added.

I tried to disable autolayout on xib file but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is probably caused by not setting `picker.view. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` before adding it as a subview.

However, in my opinion you should add a `TransactionsPickerViewController` as a child view controller, instead of just using its view. See the sections: [Implementing a Custom Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW12) and [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81).

Comment: this seems to work, however seting autoresizemask to NO causing clickable components on the child view not respond to interactions, as  they were lying somewhere else

Comment: @Xylian: As I said in my answer, you shouldn't add the view from a different controller directly. Use the view controller containment instead.